# Slicer control not refreshing in power bi composite model

Tags: powerbi, composite

For one of our clients we have a composite model where some data is fetched using Direct Query from SQL server and some using Import Query from Excel.
We have a sample filter page build in power bi desktop which has two slicer controls for testing. One using data from Excel (import mode) and another using data from SQL Server (direct query mode), both tables are connected to each other with 1:1 relationship. When i select any value in slicer(Direct query) the other slicer (Import query) does not refresh. But when i select any value in slicer (Import mode) the values in the second slicer(Direct query) does refresh properly.

Thanks!

We have checked all the relationships and their settings.

Comment: Check filter direction in relationship, make sure you selecte both direction (bi-directional filter).

Comment: bi-directional filter is already selected.

Comment: Please share your model and filters if you can.

Comment: Our direct query fetches data from SQL azure database. I tried the same conditions with an onPremise SQL server and it does work perfectly.

Comment: We were able to fix the issue. The two tables were connected using an UUID, we changed data types of both the UUID's fields to text fields and the slicer control started to work as expected. Strange, but did work for us.